# Trying to set my thermostat to use FAN only for cooling

Tags: wiring, furnace, thermostat, fans, cooling

I have a Bryant 60k BTU gas furnace(about 6 years old) and no AC. I can manually turn on just the FAN or leave it on AUTO for heating. I have the RITETEMP 6025 thermostat.

At the moment I am cooling the house in the summer by manually turning on the FAN from my gas furnace in combination with some open windows in my livingroom. The livingroom cools down quick from the open windows and the intake for my furnace is in the same room, so it picks up cool air and sends it to all the other rooms.

I do this by turning the fan on at the thermostat and letting it run for about 4 hours or until the bedrooms are cool, then I turn it off manually again, usually around 4AM.

Can I rewire my thermostat in a way I can achieve this automatically? For example, the house is at 85F, I select COOL on my thermostat and set the temp to 78F. The FAN runs until the house cools down to 78F then it stops.

When it gets close to the winter I will rewire for Heating as below.
At the moment I have 3 wires connected (G -Fan control, RH - Heater power and W - Heat control)

Here is the link for my thermostat manual:
http://www.ritetemp-thermostats.com/60XX/images/6025_installation_guide.pdf

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do that -- simply wire a jumper from the Y to the G terminals on your thermostat, and configure it as if you had an ordinary A/C.  That way, a call for cool will energize the fan, while heating still works as it normally would.

Comment: You shouldn't even need a jumper. Just connecting the `G` wire to `Y` at the thermostat should work.  Unless you still want to manually turn on the fan.

Comment: Thank you very much.I tested the solution and it works great. I moved the G wire to the Y and RH to RC. At least for now. To make it permanent I will jump Y to G and put the other wires like they were. Thank you again.

Comment: @Joe -- we thank people around here by upvoting and accepting their answers :)

Answer (score 0):

My Honeywell T8600 programmable thermostat has a System setting for Heat/Off/Cool that runs the fan when the temperature rises above the setting(preset to 74 degrees) when set to Cool. It is wired with the Red(R), Green(G) and White(W) wires only. The Yellow(Y) cool wire is not required as it would go to the Air Conditioner relay that I presently do not have. A Blue or Black wire may also be hooked to the Common(C) from the transformer

I realize that some newer smart thermostats may not work this way. Fan/Auto setting still works fine on mine without jumping anything.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. You should review our Help pages to see how to contribute (e.g. don't add a comment as an answer). Also, the contributors here are unpaid; complaining about their efforts, when you've contributed little, isn't exactly fair.

Comment: I have updated my post after finding a solution that may work for some thermostats. As a first time contributor a comment was not allowed...

Comment: With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//diy.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment). For now, feel free to post answers and questions.

Comment: My previous answer also works with White Rodgers model #1F78 non-programmable thermostats.